# float next to postion relative element

Tags: html, css-float, css

Is it possible to float element next to `position: relative` element. In case `position: relative` is removed by jquery, float element should re-float itself.

**CSS**

```
.yks {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    height:100%;
}

.kaks {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="yks"></div>
    <div class="kaks">see on nr kaks div mis peaks floatima yks kylge</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the `position: relative` element? Your code does not match your question.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just Wrap another DIV around the two DIV's and float both left?

I'm not too sure on what you are asking.  Maybe if you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve we could help you abit more...

Comment: incase both containers are float left, then the container "kaks" is positioned after container "yks". what i need, is container "yks" to be fixed and container "kaks" acting like "yks" was float. when i manually or jquery remove the html for "yks" then container "kaks" is positioned next to left side of the browser.